# Getting JS Regex to stop at the end of a line or at a blank space

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to modify a plugin I have for a Twitch bot that pulls out clip URLs.

The clip URL can be on its own or begin/end with text or both.

The regex I have seems to cause the plugin to become non-responsive after first use and it was working before I changed the Regex.

The original Regex captured all of the string after the URL started. I have made the following but it appears to cause a fault somewhere.

- Original
  `/(https:\/\/)?clips\.twitch\.tv\/(.*)/`
- Modified
  `/(https:\/\/)?clips\.twitch\.tv\/([^\s]*)/`

Test String(s):

```
some text *ClipURL* more text | *ClipURL* some text | some text *ClipURL* | *ClipURL*
```

Any help you could give me would be an amazing help.

Comment: `[^\s]*` can be stated more succinctly as `\S*`

Comment: If by "non-responsive after first use" you mean "is only matching the first url in the string", you need to add the "g" modifier.  If that's not what you mean, can you please clarify?

Comment: Daniel - No, I only expect one URL in the string. But the plugin becomes stuck as if it's still trying to process something and no longer captures further messages with clip URL's. It causes me to need to stop/start the bot again to reload the plugin

Comment: Hmmmm.... I'd be really surprised if the regex itself is causing that; they tend to either match or not match, there's nothing here that should cause an endless loop or the like.  Looking at the pastebin you linked in comments below -- I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, but the first place I'd check would be whether any of those functions gets stuck if fed empty values (`saveClip` in particular looks like it's doing a lot of work on a possibly-empty `message` parameter...)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, message is where the regex works on extrapolating the URL string. There is some logic to replace the URL from the message string with a blank space. Would this cause the message value to be rendered as blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does /(https://)?clips.twitch.tv/(\S*)/ not work for you? This is basically the second one.

It correctly matches :

- hhhh clips.twitch.tv/someone dddd
- clips.twitch.tv/someone dddd
- hhh clips.twitch.tv/someone
- clips.twitch.tv/someone

Comment: (\S*) actually broke the plugin and failed to load at all. I've uploaded the full js file to the following pastebin https://pastebin.com/9z3bsGVx in case there is some extra info in the file that might be relevant.

http://prntscr.com/fr63hw is a screen grab of how its injecting to Discord as of now. I ideally want the "im still clipping" to not be caught by the regex so it stays with the "but atleast" text

Comment: the js file is too long, but checkout https://regex101.com/r/eQzjQd/2. It correctly pulls out clipurls as expected.